# Where to have game identified?

Tags: discussion, game-identification

Where should I go to get a game identified if I don't have audiovisual of it? This site doesn't allow game ids without it and I don't have it.

Comment: Congratulations for reading through the help center! Thank you :)

Comment: If you stick around our website long enough to earn yourself 20 reputation, you will be granted the privilege to join our chat rooms. There is a solid, albeit not gauranteed chance we could help you there...

Comment: http://reddit.com/r/truegaming Go there.

Answer (score 10):

We have a blog post on this topic:

http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2012/08/identifying-games-when-you-cant-remember-the-name/

Other than that, I'm afraid we won't be of much help.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that. I can't remember all the stuff listed there because there're too many similar games like that that I've played (MMORPG), thanks anyway.